# CRM 2011 Get GUID For An Entity Record (Contract Renewel)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm having an issue when I'm trying to grab the GUID for a contract in CRM2011. First of all I have a workflow which creates an entity record, which than fires a plugin to renew a contract. It works fine when I'm setting the contract ID to a new GUID as seen below:

```
RenewContractRequest req = new RenewContractRequest();
req.IncludeCanceledLines = true;
req.ContractId = new Guid("1767AD4E-CAF4-E011-8D97-1CC1DEF1B5FF");
req.Status = 1;
RenewContractResponse resp = (RenewContractResponse)service.Execute(req);
```

However when I'm trying to do this:

```
Guid getContract_id = (Guid)((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"])["contractid"];

RenewContractRequest req = new RenewContractRequest();
req.ContractId = getContract_id;
req.IncludeCanceledLines = true;
req.Status = 1;
RenewContractResponse resp = (RenewContractResponse)service.Execute(req);
```

I get an exception that the given key was not present in the dictionary, which I understand as,  it hasn’t recognised the GUID I’m setting it to ? It might be something really stupid I’m doing, I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: which line throws exception? Which key was not present in which dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys thank you very much for your help.

I have figured it out myself, I have made use of Query Expressions to retrieve the Id (GUID) and the number of the specific contract. As I will have many contracts in the future I believe that was a better way of getting the Id.

Comment: hi A Robben, can you please share how you have used query expressions for this? I am also need of the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your syntax on the first line will work:-

```
Guid getContract_id = (Guid)((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"])["contractid"];
```

You can do this more simply with the following line:-

```
Guid getContract_id = (Guid)((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Id;
```

As you are firing this after the contract is created (hence the Id is the Id of the created entity you are firing the event on).

In general terms though retrieving the entity and then setting an attribute can be performed via the attributes collection:-

```
Entity myEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
Guid myId = (Guid)entity.Attributes["myIdName"];
```

Comment: An instance of type `Entity` will always have a non-null `Id` member when obtained this way, so I took the liberty of updating your answer. I hope you'll agree and if not, please free to remove the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var contract = ((Contract)context.InputParameters["Target"]);
Guid getContract_id = contract.ContractId;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not a good idea to assign Primary Keys in CRM, just let the CRM do it for you.
Second, perhaps your plugin works on Pre-creation, and pre-creation means that the record does not exist yet in the Database, but if you changed the plugin to post then you can get the GUID of the newly created record.

use:

```
Entity myContarct= ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]);

GUID contractId = myContract.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Guid getContract_id = context.PrimaryEntityId;
```

Also, it's not necessarily a bad idea to assign Primary Keys (entity id's) in CRM if you have a reason to do so.